# Combine natbib and babelbib styles

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I would like to combine the `plain` style of `babelbib`, but still be able to use `\citeauthor{author}` without having to use the `plainnat` style. Is that somehow possible?

My main problem with the `plainnat` style is that the bibliography is not numerical anymore. I would prefer the normal citation style, but in some rare cases I would like to the `\citeauthor` command.

I couldn't find a style in the natbib documentation that meet my needs. Or is there a way to write a new command for `babelbib` to be able to use a pseudo `\citeauthor` command?

Comment: I guess you're looking for `biblatex`

Comment: @egreg I tried many times to switch to `biblatex`, but I always run into some error. I'm not using any standard document class, but one from university. Right now I'm dealing with the following error `Package biblatex Error: File 'bib.bbl' not created by biblatex. [\begin{document}]`

EDIT: Maybe it has to do with the way I'm compiling the tex file. I might have to use `bibtex` in the Terminal, instead of within Sublime.

Comment: You have to recreate the `.bbl` file. Just ignore the error and run Biber.